# Sending two data blocks in one UDP message without copying the blocks?

Tags: c++, memory-management, udp

I want to send massive amount of message objects over UDP of my own definition `my_message`:

```
class my_message
{
    private:
        // Message header
        header_type header;

        // Message text
        byte * data;
    public:
        ...
}
```

However, if I send an instance of this class, the header would be sent along side the pointer (not the real data). So, the trivial idea is to copy the header and the data into a buffer before sending them.

As you know, UDP operates on messages not streams, which means there is a 1-to-1 relationship between `sendto()` and `recvfrom()`. I.e. It is impossible to `sendto()` two times and receive data in one `recvfrom()`.

My problem: Copying data into a new buffer would decrease the efficiency of my application.

One would think of splitting the send into sending header and sending data. This won't work because UDP messages are not ordered on receiving.

My Question: Is there a way to tell the application to `sendto()` the message by reading from two different sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sendmsg takes an iov, which allows you to specify data from different locations to be sent into one packet by means of an iov (IO-Vector) structure.

This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there a problem that prevents you from reading the sendmsg()'s manual page, which has examples of using sendmsg(), yourself? Your English seems fine, so why do you want to wait for someone to explain to you the same thing you can read yourself, from sendmsg()'s man page?

Comment: If there's something unclear in sendmsg()'s documentation then you can certainly, of course, ask a specific question about it. Do you know about this amazing web site called "www.google.com", where you can type in 'sendmsg example', and get links to hundreds of examples. It's quite amusing how half the question I read here can be answered by a simple google search.

Comment: You can also use `writev()` for this purpose.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, you are right dear. I read a lot but I needed a keyworld. I should have read much more.